# PHPExcel with Search Button

Tags: php, search

I want to search for a string that compares it to the array and outputs
the cell and its corresponding rows.

Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" class="contact_form" method = "post">
            <p>Please enter your name:</p>
            <input name="fname" id="fname" type="fname"/><br/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

<?php
    /** Include path **/
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');

    /** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
    include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


    $inputFileName = './check.xlsx';  // File to read
    //echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory to identify the format<br />';
    try {
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());    
    }

    echo '<hr />';
    echo "<pre>";
    $data =  array();
    $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell_raw) {
            $data[$cell_raw->getRow()][$cell_raw->getColumn()] = $cell_raw->getValue();
            $c =$_POST['fname'];

            if ($c === $data){
                echo 'test';
            }   
        }
    }

    var_dump($data);

/* foreach($sheetData as $rec) {
    print_r($rec);
}
 */

?>
   <body>
</html>
```

I want to search for a string that compares it to the array and outputs
the cell and its corresponding rows.

Answer (score 0):

Save-index.php

```
<form action="2.php" class="contact_form" method = "post">
    <p>Please enter your name:</p>
    <input name="fname" id="fname" type="fname"/><br/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please say why your answer is the solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Save 2.php

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        

<?php
    /** Include path **/
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');

    /** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
    include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


    $inputFileName = './jd.xlsx';  // File to read
    //echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory to identify the format<br />';
    try {
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());    
    }

    echo '<hr />';
    echo "<pre>";
    $data =  array();
    $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell_raw) {
            $data[$cell_raw->getRow()][$cell_raw->getColumn()] = $cell_raw->getValue();
            $c =$_POST['fname'];
 echo "</br><b>";
echo $cell_raw;
echo "</br></b>";

 $strsearch = (strpos($cell_raw, $c) !== FALSE);
 if($strsearch){

   echo "<b> Results found for " .$c."</b>";

}

else{
   echo "No results found for $c";
}

            if ($c == $cell_raw){
   
echo "</b></br>";
                echo '<b>if check - Match </b> ';
            } 
   else{
   
echo "</b></br>";
   echo "if check - 0"; } 
   echo "</br>";
    $search =array($cell_raw);
if (in_array($c, $search)) {
    echo "<b>array check - Got $c </b>";
}
else {
    echo "array check- No results - $c";
}
 echo "</br>";  
        }
    }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 

echo "</br>"; 
     echo "var_dump";
echo "</br>";
        var_dump($data);
 
echo "</br>"; 
        echo "print_r"; 
echo "</br>";
     print_r ($data);

/* foreach($sheetData as $rec) {
    print_r($rec);
}
 */
 

?>

   <body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why people keep writing `</br>` instead of `<br>`.